# Angular2 + RxJS - cannot read property next of undefined

Tags: angular, functional-programming, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have created the next component:

```
export class MonthView {
  currentMonth: Moment = moment();
  currentMonth$: Observable<Moment>;
  currentMonthObserver: Observer<Moment>;
  decrement: Function;
  increment: Function;

  constructor() {
    this.currentMonth$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<Moment>) => {
      this.currentMonthObserver = observer;
    }).share();

    const decrementCounter$: Observable<Function> = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.decrement = () => {
        observer.next();
      };
    });

    const incrementCounter$: Observable<Function> = Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.increment = () => {
        observer.next();
      };
    });

    Observable
      .merge(
        decrementCounter$.map(() => - 1),
        incrementCounter$.map(() => + 1)
      )
      .startWith(0)
      .scan((currentCount: number, value: number) => currentCount + value)
      .subscribe((count: number) => {
        this.currentMonthObserver.next(this.currentMonth.clone().add(count, 'M')); //this.currentMonthObserver is undefined
      });
  }
}
```

The Problem: 
I am getting: `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined` for the `this.currentMonthObserver.next` line (see the comment in the posted code).

*NOTE:* I have followed the tutorial on this blog, and I am a totally new to RxJS: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services

template:

```
<month-board [current-month]="currentMonth$"></month-board>
<button (click)="decrement()">Prev</button>
<button (click)="increment()">Next</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code `this.currentMonthObserver = observer;` in

```
this.currentMonth$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<Moment>) => {
   this.currentMonthObserver = observer;
 }).share();
```

will only be executed when you subscribe to `this.currentMonth`.
Therefore `this.currentMonthObserver` is `null` because it's not initialized.

```
constructor() {
  this.currentMonth$=new Subject().startWith(0).share();
}

increment() {
  this.currentMonth$.next(1);
}

decrement() {
  this.currentMonth$.next(-1);
}
```

Comment: Can you point on a way to initialize it before I am getting the exception? I am subscribing to it in a child component.

Comment: I'm not sure from your code what you actually want to accomplish. Just to make this step work you would need to call `this.currentMonth.subscribe();`.

Comment: I have 2 buttons on the template which should move the ui to the next and prev month. please see the template (in the updated question)

Comment: Seems to be lot of fuzz for just incrementing decrementing. I guess I would need more details about what you try to accomplish. I would start with something I added to my answer but I don't know how to proceed because your requirements are unclear to me.

Comment: I will try to clear myself. Imagine a component as seen in the template and in the image (in the updated answer). clicking the next button should move the calendar to the next month, clicking the prev button should move it to the previous month. Also there is a child component which is rendering the calendar (as seen in the template).

Comment: Is it even a good practice to pass Observables between components?

Comment: I would use `@Input()` and `@Output()` to pass the values itself instead of passing `Observable`s around, but I'm not a specialist in TS observables myself. I use only Dart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105449/discussion-between-vlio20-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am subscribing to the observable, but still it throws an error saying observer is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

not sure **exactly** what you're trying to do, but assuming you have buttons in your view to inc and dec your month, I think you can simplify quite a bit:

```
export class MonthView {
  currentMonth$: Observable<Moment>;
  tickMonth$: new Subject<Number>();

  constructor() {
    this.currentMonth$ = tickMonth$
      .scan((myMoment: Moment, tickMonthValue: number) => myMoment.clone().add(tickMonthValue, 'M'))
      .startWith(new Moment());
  }
}
```

then in your view you can do `(click)="tickMonth$.next(1)"` and `(click)="tickMonth$.next(-1)"` respectively to increment and decrement the month

Then you simply use `currentMonth | async` to get your month